# What library can I use with UWP apps/ASP.NET Core/.NET 4.5.2 apps ?

Tags: win-universal-app, portable-class-library

As I code I want to share across both (App Insights, REST API Calls..) I am trying to figure out what type of project to make. At first I was looking at Portable Class Libraries but they seem to be for the past and not for UWP/.NET core.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use a Portable Class Library type, you can select the supported targets.

[image]

Comment: When I add project I don't even see this item in 2015. I see it for Xamerin and things but I don't see the plain  'Portable Class Library' Project...  Ill try again tomorrow to find it

Comment: In the latest VS 2015 release, select *New Project* **Class Library (Portable for iOS, Android and Windows)**. This will give you a PCL project for which you can fine-tune the desired platform targets after initialization.

Comment: I got it. It was not worded in a straight forward way as previous versions